# problem with running raster calculator in grassgis

Tags: grass-gis, ndvi

When I was trying to do NDVI with grassGIS I faced a problem. I cannot run the raster calculation. When I looked to the command console I see that

> (Sat Feb 21 12:41:58 2015)
>   r.mapcalc ddes = ( LC81260522015031LGN00_B5@Tonlesap - 
>   LC81260522015031LGN00_B4@Tonlesap ) / ( 
>   LC81260522015031LGN00_B5@Tonlesap + LC81260522015031LGN00_B4@Tonlesap
>   ) (Sat Feb 21 12:42:10 2015) Command finished (12 sec)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/grass64/etc/wxpython/gui_core/goutput.py", line 874, in
>   OnCmdDone
>
> event.onDone(cmd = event.cmd, returncode = event.returncode)   File
>   "/usr/lib/grass64/etc/wxpython/modules/mcalc_builder.py", line 499, in
>   OnDone
>
> if not mapTree.GetMap().GetListOfLayers(l_name = name): AttributeError
>   : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetMap'

Can you please tell me the reason I face this problem?`

Comment: Perhaps you could say which version of GRASS you are trying to use, and what data you are trying to process?

Comment: Which version of Grass do you have? Sometimes the message "AttributeError : 'NoneType' object has no attribute..." means that there are empty values.

Comment: Actually, i use Grass 6.4.3; I am a new baby in Grass. I know that there is no problem with my raster because i already viewed in in QGIS and i could do NDVI in QGIS.

Comment: Please consider to upgrade to the new GRASS GIS 7: http://grass.osgeo.org/news/42/15/GRASS-GIS-7-0-0/